# Google Places Api

Tags: swift, xcode, google-places-api

Какой-то бред выдает google places

```
  func searchCity(nameCity :String? = "A")
  {
    let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
    filter.type = GMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilter.city

    let placesClient = GMSPlacesClient()
    placesClient.autocompleteQuery(nameCity!, bounds: nil, filter: filter, callback: { (results, error: Error?) -> Void in

      self.filterArray.removeAll()

      if let error = error {
        print("Autocomplete error \(error)")
      }

      if results != nil {
        for result in results!
        {
          for type in result.types
          {
            if type == "locality" {
              let city = result.attributedPrimaryText.string
              let country = result.attributedSecondaryText!.string
              self.filterArray.append(["title": city, "descr":country, "id": result.placeID ?? ""])
            }
          }
        }
      }

      self.filterTableView.reloadData()
    })
  }
```

[Даже учитывая фильтр](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete?hl=ru)

```
filter.type = GMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilter.city
```

получаю много лишней информации. А при попытки ее как-то отсеять, получаю не только города, но еще и села в нагрузку.

> Мне нужно сделать поиск только по городам! Есть идеи ?

P.s не критикуйте за код, он очень грязный пока =\

Comment: судя по всему вы вместо поиска запрашиваете опции для автокомплита.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko прогуглил, но ничего не нашел для поиска, только автокомплит. Возможно у вас есть полезная ссылочка.